# p5js, How to make the color follow with the array?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want the color follow with the array, not to change the color every frame,
Like the second code color show on the array, but it is colorMode.

I don't know how making the colorMode to be the picked color, or Picked color follow with array motion.
How can I do?

> https://editor.p5js.org/fruit66677788/sketches/8wiulg7m7

> https://editor.p5js.org/fruit66677788/sketches/vnH3tYpJO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for each curve to have a consistent color from frame to frame you need to either deterministically select the same color based on the value of `x`, or you need to reset the random seed so that the random sequence of colors are selected in the same order each frame.

#### Option 1:

```
    stroke(colors[round(x - offset) % colors.length]);
```

```js
var colors = ["#ed3441", "#ffb03b", "#36acf5", "#ffd630", "#084e86", "#fcfeff"];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  let offset = -width / 10;
  noFill();

  let xStep = (height + offset * 2) / 75;
  for (let x = offset; x <= height - offset; x += xStep) {
    let num = int(1 + 1.25 * noise(x / 150, frameCount / 100));
    let arr = [PI / 8];
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      let n = sq(sq(noise(x / 10, frameCount / 200))) * (width - offset * 75);
      n = max(n, 1);
      arr.push(n);
    }

    drawingContext.setLineDash(arr);
    drawingContext.lineDashOffset = x - frameCount / 10;
    strokeWeight(xStep / 0.8);
    strokeCap(ROUND);

    stroke(colors[round(x - offset) % colors.length]);

    beginShape();

    for (let y = offset; y < width - offset; y += 5) {
      let nx =
        x + tan(y / 330 + x / 300) * 150 * cos(frameCount / 20) * sin(x / 300);
      vertex(y, nx);
    }
    endShape();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

#### Option 2:

In `setup()`

```
      seed = random(0, 9999999);
```

In `draw()` prior to the for loop:

```
      randomSeed(seed);
```

```js
var colors = ["#ed3441", "#ffb03b", "#36acf5", "#ffd630", "#084e86", "#fcfeff"];

let seed;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  seed = random(0, 9999999);
}

function draw() {
  randomSeed(seed);
  background(200);

  let offset = -width / 10;
  noFill();

  let xStep = (height + offset * 2) / 75;
  for (let x = offset; x <= height - offset; x += xStep) {
    let num = int(1 + 1.25 * noise(x / 150, frameCount / 100));
    let arr = [PI / 8];
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      let n = sq(sq(noise(x / 10, frameCount / 200))) * (width - offset * 75);
      n = max(n, 1);
      arr.push(n);
    }

    drawingContext.setLineDash(arr);
    drawingContext.lineDashOffset = x - frameCount / 10;
    strokeWeight(xStep / 0.8);
    strokeCap(ROUND);

    stroke(random(colors));

    beginShape();

    for (let y = offset; y < width - offset; y += 5) {
      let nx =
        x + tan(y / 330 + x / 300) * 150 * cos(frameCount / 20) * sin(x / 300);
      vertex(y, nx);
    }
    endShape();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```